# Kuberentes delay HorizontalPodAutoscaler on pod startup

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

Lets say I have 3 instances of my service.  I get a spike of traffic and now Kubernetes HPA says to scale up to 4.  For a period of time, about 90 seconds, the new pod will consume about 400% CPU.  Thus that will skew the averages and Kubernetes HPA will say scale from 4 to 5 and it keeps in this cycle till the averages are low enough to account for the new instance startup spike and it scales down.  How do I tell the Kubernetes HPA to ignore CPU metrics for 90 seconds when it decides to scale up?

Current HPA Configuration:

```
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-app
  minReplicas: 3
  maxReplicas: 15
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 95
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 95
```

I will also say I have dome some research and it appears that I can have something the below, but cannot find much good information on the stabilizationWindowSeconds and policies for the scaleUp Behavior.

```
behavior:
  scaleUp:
    stabilizationWindowSeconds: 0
    policies:
    - type: Percent
      value: 100
      periodSeconds: 15
    - type: Pods
      value: 4
      periodSeconds: 15
    selectPolicy: Max
```

Comment: HorizontalPodAutoscaler can't determine initial pod readiness by using CPU metrics instead it uses a flag called --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-initial-readiness-delay and the default value is 30 Sec. you can get more details on horizontal pod autoscaler [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni is -horizontal-pod-autoscaler-initial-readiness-delay a delay on the creation of the HPA or is it a delay on metrics for any new pod?

Comment: The -horizontal-pod-autoscaler-initial-readiness-delay flag is a delay on metrics for any new pod. This flag is used to ensure that the HPA has enough time to collect metrics from newly created pods and accurately determine the desired number of replicas. This delay helps to prevent the HPA from scaling up too quickly and prevents the HPA from scaling up when the metrics for newly created pods are not yet available.

Comment: Refer this [doc](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/autoscaling-in-kubernetes-why-doesnt-the-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-work-for-me-5f0094694054) for more information and also how to [setup initial delay](https://horizontal-pod-autoscaler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/configuration/#initialreadinessdelay).

Comment: @Brian is this helpful, revert back if you need any more details or assistance.

Comment: @HemanthKumar I tried what you recommended in the link and keep getting: error validating data: ValidationError(HorizontalPodAutoscaler.spec): unknown field "initialReadinessDelay".  How do I set this field within my hpa config?

Comment: initialReadinessDelay field is not supported by the version of Kubernetes you are using. make sure to use the latest version or upgrade to a version of Kubernetes that supports it. Make sure that the field is properly defined in your manifest file in the spec section of the HorizontalPodAutoscaler object.

Comment: @HemanthKumar I am on kubernetes 1.22... any idea what version that was introduced in?